# How to merge class instances in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, copy, instance

I have a class like this:

```
class Person {
    private _age: number;

    get age(): number {
        return this._age;
    }

    set age(value: number) {
        this._age = value;
    }
}
```

And an instance of that class:

```
let peter = new Person();
peter.age = 30;
```

I want to have another instance of that class by simply using the spread operator:

```
let marc = {
    ...peter,
    age: 20
}
```

But this does not result in an instance of `Person` but in an object without the getter and setter of `Person`.

Is it possible to merge class instances somehow or do I need to use `new Person()` again for `mark`?

Comment: You'll need to use new Person() again for marc to create a seperate instance of the class Person for marc. It doesn't really make sense either to spread peter, unless marc is peters clone. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah actually the example is not the best. Indeed I want to have a clone of Peter and work with the clone without modifying Peter.

Comment: If you don't want to modify peter, why do you need access to its getters and setters? `Object.entries()` and `Object.values()` and such will give you an array containing copies of those properties ( providing they are primitives, else they'll be references ) on peter that you can safely work with. But does not give you the getters and setters. So it goes back to just creating a new instance again if you do need the getters and setters, but want them to be tied to their own scope instead of peters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spread syntax is supposed to produce plain object, so it isn't applicable. If new class instance is needed, it should be created with `new`. If an object has to be merged with other properties, `Object.assign` can be used:

```
let marc = Object.assign(
    new Person()
    peter,
    { age: 20 }
);
```

Since `Object.assign` processes own enumerable properties, the result may be undesirable or unexpected, depending on class internals; it will copy private `_age` but not public `age` from `peter`.

In any special case a class should implement utility methods like `clone` that is aware of class internals and creates an instance properly.

Answer (score 0):

In OOP terms you don't define your properties after creating instances, you define them in your `class`

In your example both Marc and Peter have an age so you don't need to merge anything. You could use the contructor to pass a specific value for that instance:

```
let marc = new Person("marc", 20)
let peter = new Person("peter", 30)

class Person {
    constructor(private name:string, private age:number){
       console.log("I am " + this.name + " my age is " + this.age)
    }
}
```

If there is a property that no person except Marc has, then you can let Marc extend Person.

```
class Person {

}

class Marc extends Person {
    car:string
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations although I do not want to merge classes but instances of the same class. My hope was to not be forced to call a constructor and assign each and every value to a clone instance. I think to provide a `clone()` method as @estus suggested will be the solution in my case.